# To access selected radio button value in angular controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am unable to get the value of a selected radio button in angular controller. The reportTypeId I use in angular controller does not fetch the value of the radio button. Can someone guide me where exactly I am wrong ?

HTML

```
 <div class="col-md-3">
     <input type="radio" ng-model="reportTypeRadio" value="reportType.reportTypeId"> 
     <a href="#reportTypeEntityList/{{reportType.reportTypeId}}">                    
       {{reportType.reportTypeLabel}}
    </a>
</div>
```

Controller

```
mdmApp.controller('Controller', function($scope, $http, $location, $routeParams) {

    $scope.reportTypeRadio = reportTypeId;

    $scope.viewReportTypeEntityList = function() {
        $location.path('/reportTypeEntityList/' +reportTypeId);
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use model value from `ngModel` directive:

```
$scope.viewReportTypeEntityList = function() {
    $location.path('/reportTypeEntityList/' + $scope.reportTypeRadio);
};
```

Comment: still the value does not get passed on to '$scope.reportTypeRadio'. Is there something wrong with my html ?

Comment: I think you also need to add each radio button a name (the same for each button in the group).

Comment: I added and tried the same but still unable to fetch the value 'reportType.reportTypeId' in '$scope.reportTypeRadio'

Comment: I get this error message 'SEVERE: Class java.lang.Long can not be instantiated using a constructor with a single String argument'

Comment: It's not javascript problem, it's your java something. I guess you need to fix that first.

Comment: I could see this too in my console. Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "$scope.reportTypeRadio"

Comment: I get the url like this http://localhost:7001/xxx/#/rEntityList/undefined. I should have got the 'reportTypeId' value in url but it is undefined as it the value from radio button couldnt be fetched.

Answer (score 0):

It worked. I just made the below changes to my html. used ng-value instead of value, and $parent in ng-model to use the parent scope of the ng-repeat directive.

```
<div class="col-md-3">
 <input type="radio" ng-model="$parent.reportTypeRadio" ng-value="reportType.reportTypeId"> 
 <a href="#reportTypeEntityList/{{reportType.reportTypeId}}">                    
   {{reportType.reportTypeLabel}}
</a>
```